# How to Wait for an element to be filled of text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I use **Selenium** + **Python** and I work on a Page that data is filled from JS and is Dynamic every 10 seconds but it's not important because I will run it once a week, I want to wait as long as the `td with id='e5'` get its value and be filled Or rather until the site is **fully loaded**, The site address is as follows :
[Site Address](http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=2400322364771558)

But i dont find Suitable **Expected Conditions** for this job :

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=2400322364771558')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.staleness_of((By.ID, 'e5')))
    print(driver.find_element_by_id('e5').text)
    driver.close()
```

I speak about this tag if you cant find it :

[image: Tag location]

Comment: Do you mean you want to start script and print out `#e5` text value each time it changed? Without timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to constantly check elements' text value

```
import time

pause = 1 # set interval between value checks in seconds

field = driver.find_element_by_id('e5')
value = field.text

while True:
    if field.text != value:
        value = field.text
        print(value)
    time.sleep(pause)
```

If you want to use WebdriverWait try

```
field = driver.find_element_by_id('e5')
value = field.text

while True:
    WebDriverWait(driver, float('inf')).until(lambda driver: field.text != value)
    value = field.text
    print(value)
```

Comment: Yes it's is very smart way, is there another way ?

Comment: @SinaOrg I've added another way, but still cannot test it - hour have passed, but value is the same :)

Comment: i really love your second way and use it but we don't need time.sleep() in loop,int not danger ?

Comment: @SinaOrg I'm not sure I understand. Can you clarify?

Comment: i think something like infinity loop if site is load so fast or take lot of ram to loop be so fast

Comment: @SinaOrg your warnings are still not clear, but both suggested options are infinite loops. If you want to reduce ram load you can use first option ans set `pause` option, or use it in second option - `WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=float('inf'), poll_frequency=pause)`

Answer (score 0):

There is an Expected Condition for that:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'e5')))
```

You don't need to wait for the element to be stale, you need it to be visible on the DOM.

Comment: No it's not work,the tag is display but dont have any value --> its empty